# insert a field value into a table from c# Form application

Tags: sql-server

I want to Insert a DateTime variable into a table by " Insert into " , I mean by using from coding not wizard. 
fro example I have a table which has a some field and one of them is Time_1 and I've write a procedure which its duty is filling Information to my table and in my procedure I've used from : 
Insert into my_table 
values
('@name','@last_Name',@ID,@Time)
but SQL show error when I enter 12:45:00 for @Time 
so please tell me how to enter times into my filed . 
Thanks in advance

create procedure Insert_List
@code int, @name nvarchar(20),@lastname nvarchar(40),@time1 datetime,@time2 datetime,
@time3 datetime,@price1 int,@price2 int, @B1 int , @V1 int , @M1 int 
as 
begin
insert into Employee
values 
(@code,@name,@lastname,@time1,@time2,@time3,@price1,@price2,@B1,@V1,@M1)
end

//and I try to execute my procedure by these information

execute Insert_List 1,'Keyvan','Fardi',10:00:00,18:15:00,19:10:00,10,10,10,10
select * from employee

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near ':'.

Answer (score 1):

> Insert into my_table values ('@name','@last_Name',@ID,@Time)

Since you are using a parameterized SQL statement, do not enclose the parameters in quotes.  Instead:

```
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (@name, @last_Name, @ID, @Time);
```

If you are still getting an error, post the error message and all proc code.

Comment: Hello Mr Dan Guzman , maybe I did't describe my problem in a correct way , my  problem is I don't know how to put a time in values , for example we put names between single quotations , so is there any thing that I have to use in order to put times in example which I've mentioned ? for example should I use from dollar sign or something like that?

Comment: I've forgotten to tell that I define Time field as time(7)

Comment: The nice thing about parameters is that they are strongly typed values in native (binary) format so you never need to enclose in quotes or format the values in a particular way.  So if the @Time parameter is declared as a time, datetime, datetime2, etc. data type, you will not have problems.  Again, post your code and error message if you need a better answer.  We can only guess otherwise.